# What is wrong with this code ? It is not showing any error but It is also not showing any output

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying a speech-to-text program . I have written this code but it is not showing any output and also not showing any error. It is not reading my speech. Can't find any solution to it. Please help.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser as wb

r1 = sr.Recognizer()
r2 = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
 print('Say Hello')
 print('Speak')
 audio = r2.listen(source)

if 'Hello' in r1.recognize_google(audio):
 r1 = sr.Recognizer()
 url = 'https://www.google.com/'
 with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('search')
    audio = r1.listen(source)

    try:
        get = r1.recognize_google(audio)
        print(get)
        wb.get().open_new(url + get)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print('Not recognised')
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print('try again'.format(e))
```

Comment: Does the program terminate? The only way I can see this program producing *no* output is if either `Recognizer` or `Microphone` doesn't return. Without knowing either is, it's hard to say what the problem might be.

Comment: All your print statements are inside `with sr.Microphone() as source` context managers, which might not actually do anything. I'd try introspecting `sr.Microphone()` directly to see what state it has.

Comment: Also a simple test but try making the very first line a `print` statement to confirm there's not something more fundamentally wrong here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After risking my marriage by repeatedly and annoyingly shouting hello at my computer, what it looks like is the captured audio is always lower case:

```
Say Hello
Speak
> /Users/matt/repos/stackoverflow/test.py(16)<module>()
-> if 'Hello' in audio_result:
(Pdb) l
 11     
 12     audio_result = r1.recognize_google(audio)
 13     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
 14     
 15     
 16  -> if 'Hello' in audio_result:
 17     
 18         r1 = sr.Recognizer()
 19         url = 'https://www.google.com/'
 20         with sr.Microphone() as source:
 21             print('search')
(Pdb) audio_result
'hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello'
(Pdb) 'Hello' in audio_result
False
(Pdb) 'hello' in audio_result
True
```

So clearly `'Hello'` should be `'hello'`.

After the switch and a retry, my browser opened to the url https://www.google.com/hello, which didn't resolve, but I think this will get you further.

HTH.